# Detect Chrome Presentation mode from appleScript

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

Now I have AppleScript that I'm running each time on restart. Here is line from that AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "f" using {command down
    , shift down}
```

Browser should always stay in presentation mode(without tabs). On first run Script making Presentation mode but on second he is returning to normal mode. For now I don't have ideas how to fix it from AppleScript.
Thanks in advance.